# XCTest - Unable to understand / implement expectations in unit tests (to test aysnc code)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, xctest

(NOTE - I'm developing for macOS, so please ... iOS-specific advice won't help me)

What I'm trying to do:
I have an app component that performs a short task on a background thread, and then, if certain conditions are met, asynchronously sends out a notification on the main thread.

NOTE - I am ***not using NSNotification*** in my app code. I am using my own custom notification mechanism. So, any solution related to NSNotification is not applicable to me.

I'm writing a unit test for the above mentioned app component, and simply **want to check if that notification was indeed sent or not**. My test has to be able to wait a second or so to give the notification time to reach its subscriber/observer, before performing an assertion.

I want to be able to test **both possible cases** in my tests: Both are normal scenarios.

- Notification was sent.
- Notification was not sent.

After hours of reading several docs and code samples, I don't understand how to achieve this with expectations.

I just want to wait one second in my test. Is it really this complicated ?

- sleep() doesn't work
- DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(time) doesn't work
- Timer doesn't work

Here's the app component that needs to be tested, and its unit test:

**In the below code, where do I put expectation.fulfill() ???**

```
class ComponentBeingTested {

    func methodBeingTested() {

        doSomeWork()
        if certainConditionsAreMet {
             DispatchQueue.main.async {sendOutNotification()}
        }
    }
}

...

class UnitTestForComponentBeingTested: XCTestCase {

    let objectBeingTested = ComponentBeingTested()

    func testMethodBeingTested() {

          let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Notification was sent")

          // Call the code being tested
          objectBeingTested.methodBeingTested()

          // How do I do this with expectations ??? Where does expectation.fulfill() go ?
          waitForOneSecond()

          XCTAssertTrue(notificationSent)      // Assume the value of notificationSent is available

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of trial and error, this works great for me:

**Description**: I basically created a helper function in my test case class that contains all the boilerplate expectation/wait code. It does the following:

1 - Creates an expectation (i.e. XCTestExpectation) as a formality.

2 - Calls my (arbitrary) test case assertion code (passed in as a closure) on some global queue thread after the intended delay period. Once this assertion code has completed, the expectation is fulfilled (again, a formality).

3 - Waits on the expectation by calling XCTestCase.wait(timeout). This ensures that the main thread / run loop is kept alive while my assertion code completes on this other thread.

Then, in my test case, I simply invoke that helper function, providing it with a wait period and some code to execute (i.e. my assertions).

This way, I have a simple and expressive reusable function that hides all the excessive ugliness of expectations which I never thought necessary in the first place.

I can put this helper in a base class like MyAppTestCase: XCTestCase, so that it is available to all my test case classes.

NOTE - This solution can be enhanced and made even more generic/reusable, but as of now, this is quite sufficient for the purposes of the originally posted problem.

**Solution**:

```
class ComponentBeingTested {

    func methodBeingTested() {

        doSomeWork()
        if certainConditionsAreMet {
             DispatchQueue.main.async {sendOutNotification()}
        }
    }
}

...

class UnitTestForComponentBeingTested: XCTestCase {

    let objectBeingTested = ComponentBeingTested()

    // Helper function that uses expectation/wait to execute arbitrary
    // test code (passed in as a closure) after some delay period.
    func executeAfter(_ timeSeconds: Double, _ work: (@escaping () -> Void)) {

        let theExpectation = expectation(description: "some expectation")

        // Execute work() after timeSeconds seconds
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeSeconds) {

            // The call to work() will execute my test assertions
            work()

            // As a formality, fulfill the expectation
            theExpectation.fulfill()
        }

        // Wait for (timeSeconds + 1) seconds to give the work() call 
        // some time to perform the assertions
        wait(for: [theExpectation], timeout: timeSeconds + 1)
    }

    func testMethodBeingTested() {

          // Call the code being tested
          objectBeingTested.methodBeingTested()

          // Call the helper function above, to do the waiting before executing
          // the assertions
          executeAfter(0.5) {

              // Assume the value of notificationSent is computed elsewhere
              // and is available to assert at this point
              XCTAssertTrue(notificationSent)      
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach

```
func testMethodBeingTested() {

      // create expectation
      let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Notification was sent")

      // set expectation condition
      var notificationSent = false
      let observer = NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(forName: _Your_Notification_Name, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
            notificationSent = true
            expectation.fulfill()
        }

      // Call the code being tested
      objectBeingTested.methodBeingTested()

      // wait for expectation
      self.wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 5)

      XCTAssertTrue(notificationSent)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I also want to be able to test for certain cases when the notification should not be sent. In those cases, your test will fail because fulfill() has not been called. So, where would I put fulfill() if the notification is not sent ?

In other words, I want to be able to test both app scenarios - notification sent, notification not sent. In both scenarios, the expectation needs to be fulfilled somewhere. How ?

Also, I cannot use NotificationCenter because ComponentBeingTested does not use NotificationCenter to post notifications. I'm using my own custom notification logic.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [XCTNSNotificationExpectation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctnsnotificationexpectation), which becomes fulfilled when a matching notification is posted. Different initializers are available, depending on how restrictive you want to be on the fulfilment of the expectation.

To check that the notification is *not* sent, set `isInverted` to `true` on the expectation object.

Then just add a call to `waitForExpectations(timeout:handler:)` at the end of your test.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The only issue is that I am not using NSNotification in my app. I have my own custom notification mechanism. I'm guessing that XCTNSNotificationException cannot be used in my case.

Comment: Try replacing your waitForOneSecond method with waitForExpectations, does that help?

Comment: I tried waitForExpectations (all the different method variations) before I posted this question. The fundamental problem I'm facing is that I need the expectation to be fulfilled in both cases - whether or not the notification is sent. I have not tried setting isInverted on the expectation. I will try that out and let you know if it works.

Comment: If you're not bothered about the outcome of the expectation, then I recommend following @Asperi's method of using XCTWaiter to wait for the expectation to fulfill or time out, but then not checking the result.

Comment: Hi Oletha, I have found a solution that fits my needs very well. I have posted this as an answer. Thanks for your help.